# Opening OneLogin links via iframe

Tags: single-sign-on, onelogin

I am using **OneLogin** for **Single-Sign-On** authorization.
Is it possible to open **OneLogin** link via **iFrame**?

For example: **https://honey-dev.onelogin.com/launch/XXXXXX,**
where **'XXXXXX'** - appliation id.

For now, I am getting an error:
[Refused to display 'https://honey-dev.onelogin.com/client/apps' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zka5.png)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little late, but can be useful if someone else is looking for it:

Go to `Administration Dashboard -> Settings -> Account Settings`.

On the page, look for `Disable Framing Protection (X-Frame-Options)` and check the box.

Now, you can embed OneLogin as you wish, so just grab your application ID and you can use launch links like Taras Vegera wrote.